# why are bash vs tcsh file timestamps different?

Tags: bash, rsync, timestamp

on my xubuntu 19.10-amd64 system I have cron running backup jobs every midnight.  The destination directories created by the rsync command should therefore have timestamps of 00:00.   However I'm seeing weirdness in the timestamps.
tcsh (my preferred interactive shell) correctly shows timestamps of 00:00 on successive days, but bash and /bin/sh both list all the destination directories with timestamps of the incorrect date and time (see screen capture).  Because the timestamps are identical, "ls -lt" ordering is arbitrary (i.e. wrong) in the /bin/sh script, and my script fails to find the "oldest" backup.
Both source and destination are on local ext4 filestems (local SSD to local HDD); there is no nfs involved and no remote system. 
If I manually "touch" one of the destination folders, both bash and tcsh report the new timestamp.
 I can't find any prior discussion of different shells reporting differing timestamps.   Any advice on where should I look for help troubleshooting this?  thanks...

```
dean/ 101 >tcsh
dean/ 89 >ls -ltd /mnt/HDD4/Backups/CUDA1.home.0.*
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov 18 00:00 /mnt/HDD4/Backups/CUDA1.home.0.2019-11-18/
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov 17 00:00 /mnt/HDD4/Backups/CUDA1.home.0.2019-11-17/
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov 16 00:00 /mnt/HDD4/Backups/CUDA1.home.0.2019-11-16/
dean/ 90 >bash
dean@CUDA1:~$ ls -ltd /mnt/HDD4/Backups/CUDA1.home.0.*
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov 14 16:31 /mnt/HDD4/Backups/CUDA1.home.0.2019-11-16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov 14 16:31 /mnt/HDD4/Backups/CUDA1.home.0.2019-11-17
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov 14 16:31 /mnt/HDD4/Backups/CUDA1.home.0.2019-11-18
dean@CUDA1:~$ sudo touch /mnt/HDD4/Backups/CUDA1.home.0.2019-11-18
[sudo] password for dean: 
dean@CUDA1:~$ !ls
ls -ltd /mnt/HDD4/Backups/CUDA1.home.0.*
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov 18 12:52 /mnt/HDD4/Backups/CUDA1.home.0.2019-11-18
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov 14 16:31 /mnt/HDD4/Backups/CUDA1.home.0.2019-11-16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov 14 16:31 /mnt/HDD4/Backups/CUDA1.home.0.2019-11-17
dean@CUDA1:~$ exit
exit
dean/ 91 >!ls
ls -ltd /mnt/HDD4/Backups/CUDA1.home.0.*
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov 18 12:52 /mnt/HDD4/Backups/CUDA1.home.0.2019-11-18/
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov 17 00:00 /mnt/HDD4/Backups/CUDA1.home.0.2019-11-17/
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov 16 00:00 /mnt/HDD4/Backups/CUDA1.home.0.2019-11-16/
```

Comment: Is `ls` aliased in either interactive shell (to `ls -u` for example)?

Comment: oh good point I hadn't thought of that...   yup that was it.  
both shells had  "ls" aliased to different things.     I'll write it up as the answer and accept it.   thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per [steeldriveer](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver)'s comment, both shells inherited different aliases for "ls".  Explicitly executing /bin/ls gives consistent results.   solved.
Thanks.